# Creating web-service in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

Hi I am new to `Ruby and Rails` platform. Can anyone one tell me the procedure to create a simple web-service in Rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ws-rubyrails/index.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146669/rails-using-another-apps-soap-interface) ,[this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527969.do), and this [page](http://areyoufuckingcoding.me/2012/02/27/go-powered-webservices-with-rails/)

Answer (score -6):

I recommend this book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Ruby on Rails Tutorial
Learn Web Development with Rails
Michael Hartl

create a simple web-service in Rails.

1. rails new projectname
2. cd projectname
3. bundle install
4. rails s